# Joining multiple columns into one with union, exclude results with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to join columns from multiple tables to one column, in my case column 'battery_value' and 'technical_value' into column 'value'. I want to fetch data for only given category_ids, but because of UNION, I get data from other tables as well.

I have 4 tables:
Table: car

```
car_id   model_name
1        e6
```

Table: battery

```
battery_category_id    car_id    battery_value
1                      1         125 kW
```

Table: technical_data

```
technical_category_id  car_id    technical_value
1                      1         5
3                      1         2008
```

Table: categories

```
category_id     category_name     category_type
1               engine power      battery
1               seats             technical
3               release year      technical
```

From searching, people are suggesting that I use union to join these columns. My query now looks like this:

```
SELECT CARS.car_id
       category_id,
       CATEGORIES.category_name,
       value,
FROM   CARS
           left join (SELECT BATTERY.battery_category_id AS category_id,
                             BATTERY.car_id              AS car_id,
                             BATTERY.value               AS value
                      FROM   BATTERY
                      WHERE `BATTERY`.`battery_category_id` IN (1)
                      UNION
                      SELECT TECHNICAL_DATA.technical_category_id AS category_id,
                          TECHNICAL_DATA.car_id            AS car_id,
                          TECHNICAL_DATA.value             AS value
                      FROM   TECHNICAL_DATA
                      WHERE `TECHNICAL_DATA`.`technical_category_id` IN (3))
    tt
                     ON CARS.car_id = tt.car_id
           left join CATEGORIES
                     ON category_id = CATEGORIES.id
```

So the result I want is this, because I only want to get the data where category_id 1 is in battery table:

```
car_id   category_id   category_name   technical_value
1        1             engine power    125 kW
1        3             release year    2008
```

but with the query above I get this, category_id 1 from technical table is included which is not something I want:

```
car_id   category_id   category_name   value
1        1             engine power    125 kW
1        1             seats           125 kW
1        3             release year    2008
```

How can get exclude the 'seats' row?

Comment: @Strawberry Hi! Yes, I excluded a lot of other information in car table just to show the problem at hand.

Comment: My idea was to have separate tables for battery information and technical information, because battery_category_id and technical_category_id are the primary keys in their respective table (managed to switch the order, will edit). Then I will use their primary keys to find out what type of category it is, because one car can have multiple battery data, I only added 1 for this scenario.

Comment: If you're not interested in technical category_id 1, why not filter it out?

Comment: I cannot confidentally say what the PRIMARY KEY is on your latter tables. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @ScootCork I have over 100 categories in each table so I want to be able to filter by the few categories that I do want instead of filtering by all the categories I do not want.

Comment: @Strawberry If you mean the two last ones, the first is the result I want to achieve and the second is the result of my posted query. If you mean categories table, the combination of category_id and category_name is the primary key (same with technical and battery actually). Sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Why do you want in the results for technical_value = 5 when category_name  = engine power?

Comment: @forpas A silly copy-paste mistake when I edited the tables. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the results you want, I don't see why the `cars` table is needed.  Then, you seem to need an additional key for the join to `categories` based on *which* table it is referring to.

So, I suggest:

```
SELECT tt.*, c.category_name
FROM ((SELECT b.battery_category_id AS category_id,
              b.car_id AS car_id, b.value AS value,
              'battery' as which
       FROM BATTERY b
       WHERE b.battery_category_id IN (1)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT td.technical_category_id AS category_id,
              td.car_id AS car_id, td.value AS value,
              'technical' as which
       FROM TECHNICAL_DATA td
       WHERE td.technical_category_id IN (3)
      )
     ) tt LEFT JOIN
     CATEGORIES c
     ON c.id = tt.category_id AND
        c.category_type = tt.which;
```

That said, you seem to have a problem with your data model, if the join to `categories` requires "hidden" data such as the type.  However, that is outside the scope of the question.